# android:justificationMode="inter_word" is not Working on oppo f21 pro 5g Android 13 (API level 33)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This the Text view i had  implemented  it working on most of the devices

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAboutUs"

                style="@style/font_16sp_roboto_medium_black"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:letterSpacing="0.02"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="1dp"
                android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                android:text="@string/about_us" />
```